# count how many replaced with replaceFirst and StringUtils.countMatches

Tags: java, replace, count

I'm trying to replace all the " n" to " normal" in my string result. And i want to count how many were replaced

[image]

I tried 2 different methods i found on stackoverflow but neither seem to work.

Method 1 with replaceFirst:

```
while (!result.replaceFirst(" n", " normal").equals(result)) {
            result = result.replaceFirst(" n", " normal");
            normal++;
        }
```

It gave me an infinite loop.

The second method i tried somthing with StringUtils:

```
normal = StringUtils.countMatches(" n", " normal");
```

but it underlines countMatches in red and doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the first routine goes into infinite loop is because you are replacing the string inside the loop , and every replace adds another "n" into the string.You should do the counting and replacing separately :

```
String s = "abc n def n ghi n";
int count = 0;
for( int i=0; i < s.length(); i++ ) {
    if( s.charAt(i) == 'n' ) {
        count++;
    } 
}   
s=s.replaceAll("n", "normal");

System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Ok, i get it. Just one problem. I also need to take the white space before the n like this  ' n'. Is that possible with a char?

Comment: There are many ways to do this.One way to do it would be just calling this before doing anything : `s=s.replaceAll(" n", "n");`.